# Does kata container substitute Docker in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kata-containers

I have deployed Kubernetes with Docker before. I have trouble deploying K8s with Kata Container. Does kata container completely replace Docker in Kubernetes? So I have to uninstall Docker from my nodes to make it work? I am so confused right now.

Answer (score 1):

Kata containers work with Docker. You can look at this git repo where they have details setting up Kata with Docker and kubernetes both.
[Kata Deploy](https://github.com/kata-containers/packaging/tree/master/kata-deploy)